# How can I make a textbox perform a backspace when I'm Not typing in it VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox, controls, keypress, keydown

I'm making a hex keyboard converter with two TextBoxes: TextBox1 for typing in the key you want to convert, and TextBox2 for displaying what you converted.

So far I have gotten it to convert as I typed, but when I press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, TextBox1 will erase the key but TextBox2 will remain with the same converted code, meaning I have to go to TextBox2 to erase it manually.

Is there a way I can make it so that when I press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> while typing in TextBox1, the TextBox2 will go back as well? And is there a way I can tell it how many spaces to go back?

Comment: Please provide some code. It would be nice to see the code which converts the input and places it in the second textbox

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are building the string by capturing each key. But couldn't you just convert the entire contents of TextBox1 and put it into TextBox2?

This is another way of doing it. See if it works

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox2.Text = shiftCharacters(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Function shiftCharacters(input As String) As String
    Return String.Join("", input.Select(Function(c) ChrW(AscW(c) + 1)))
End Function
```

Since I don't know how you convert each character, I just shifted each character up by 1.

Here are some images

[image]

Then I deleted 123 with backspace.

[image]

Is this going to work?